# How do I seperate the code when building a public component library, in which all components communicate with my server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture, open-source

I've never published a library before, but learned how to do so today. I have an idea for a product I've started working on which is based on a react component library. It is somewhat similar to Clerk. Not in its purpose but more in it exposing components to be used by the client, but also storing data for the client.

So two main questions arise when it comes to security and structure:

1. Do I just keep all the async logic for each component within itself? Usually when I build an app for example, I'll have the component logic then the async calls from redux/custom hooks etc. I know it is possible of course to just make the calls from the component itself - is that the correct way to do it in such a library?
2. How do I communicate with my server from every client's app that's been consuming my components, without me exposing my sensitive data that is usually stored in environment variables in my app?

Tbh I feel very unconfident about how to structure this thing correctly and securely. Would appreciate a clear understanding on the separation and structure of all the logic in such a library.

** Also no idea what tags I should use here feel free to suggest other ones please.